# How to print double 2D array in showMessageDialog?

Tags: java, arrays, string, double, stringbuilder

I'm writing a program to inverse matrix
so I stored the result in

```
double matrix[][] = new double[n][2*n];
```

and when I print the result in consol it'll be correct
but now I try to improve the program and I want to print array in

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
```

so I write

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(n*n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
        builder.append(matrix[i][j]);
        builder.append(",");
    }
    builder.append("\n");
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, builder.toString(), "The inverse matrix is:", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

now the problim output should be double for example like this

```
-0.14285714285714285    0.2857142857142857
0.4285714285714286  -0.35714285714285715
```

But every time with any input matrix I get same result

```
1.0,0.0,
-0.0,1.0,
```

Thank you.. and sorry my English is not good

---

Ok, It solved
I Keep the size of matrix as

```
double matrix[][] = new double[n][2*n];
```

and correct the loop as Reimeus said with some modifying

```
for (int j = n; j < n*2; j++) {
```

Thank you all..
It is the first question in this great site and I got answer quickly.. Thank you very much

Comment: Why is the inverse of the matrix not square? In your above code it is n by 2n

Comment: Have you validated, that the matrix indeed does contain the correct values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your matrix is n*n. You need to correct this line:

```
  double matrix[][] = new double[n][2*n];
```

To

```
  double matrix[][] = new double[n][n];
```

If size is correct, please correct the iteration.

For formatting, please use formatting class `DecimalFormat` as below:

```
 String fPattern = "0.00000000000000000"; //please supply the right format pattern
 DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat(fPattern);
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(n*n);
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
      builder.append(dFormat.format(matrix[i][j]));
      builder.append(",");
    }
    builder.append("\n");
 }
```

Please use `0.00000000000000000` as pattern if you always wish to have fixed length of decimals. If you want varying length, please use `#.#################`.

Comment: That does not answer OP's question.

Comment: Ok I correct it to 
`double matrix[][] = new double[n][n];`

but the problem still
how to convert "double" to "String" without losing the accuracy

Comment: Ok, It solved
I Keep the size of matrix as
`double matrix[][] = new double[n][2*n];`
and correct the loop as Reimeus said with some modifying
`for (int j = n; j < n*2; j++) {`

Thank you all..
It is the first question in this site and I got answer quickly.. Thank you very much

Comment: Updated the answer with formatting. I noticed that array dimension and iteration size wasn't matching and that was the issue. I thought size was incorrect but it was the iteration. Good to know, it SO answers solved your problem.